# Using sessionStorage to update button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sessionstorage

I'm using sessionStorage to update a button text. I've got the button IDs stored in an array. My question is how do I update the button text using the sessionStorage values? Below is an example.

```
var btnArr = [fruit, veggies, dessert];
if (sessionStorage.getItem("val0")) {
    button0 = sessionStorage.getItem("val0");
    button1 = sessionStorage.getItem("val1");
    button2 = sessionStorage.getItem("val2");
    for(i = 0; i<btnArr.length; i++){
        $('#'+btnArr[i]).text("button"+i); // How do I update this value here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array` to store button values same as you've `btnArr` array for the values. Get the values from `sessionStorage` and can be used in `for` loop using `index`.

```
var btnArr = [fruit, veggies, dessert];


var buttonValues = []; // For buttons


if (sessionStorage.getItem("val0")) {
    // Add values in array
    buttonValues.push(sessionStorage.getItem("val0"));
    buttonValues.push(sessionStorage.getItem("val1"));
    buttonValues.push(sessionStorage.getItem("val2"));

    for (i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
        $('#' + btnArr[i]).text(buttonValues[i]); // Use values from array
    }
}
```

**OR**

Using `sessionStorage` values in `array` directly.

```
var btnArr = [fruit, veggies, dessert];
if (sessionStorage.getItem("val0")) {
    var buttonValues = [sessionStorage.getItem("val0"), sessionStorage.getItem("val1"), sessionStorage.getItem("val2")]; // Add values in array

    for (i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
        $('#' + btnArr[i]).text(buttonValues[i]); // Get values from array
    }
}
```